# Why is my SQL Server query not returning the correct data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need help figuring out why I am not getting any results with this query.

My boss already pulled the data, so I know it's there. But for some reason I am not getting anything:

```
SELECT SessionSID as 'ResponseID'
    , TargetID
    , TargetName
    , SurveyNumber
    , ABCSurveyName
    , SurveyID as 'RedirectedSurveyID'
    , SupplierID
    , SupplierName
    , RespondentID
    , PID
    , IPAddress
    , IsLive
    , EntryDate
    , LastDate
    , LK_ResponseStatusID as 'Response Status Code'
    , ClientLK_ResponseStatusID as 'Client Response Status Code'
    , LK_SupplierLinkTypeName
    , ProjectID
    , ParentSID 
    , TargetCPI
    , SupplierCPI
    , DefaultCPI 
FROM BI_Sessions (nolock) 
WHERE EntryDate BETWEEN   '06-07-2012'  AND '06-08-2012'  
    AND ABCSurveyName  like  'EBAY4263-718184%' 
    AND SupplierID =  42
```

UPdated Data is here(I know I'm sorry, it's long):

```
ResponseID  TargetID    TargetName  SurveyNumber    ABCSurveyName   RedirectedSurveyID  SupplierID  SupplierName    RespondentID    PID IPAddress   IsLive  EntryDate   LastDate    Response Status Code    Client Response Status Code LK_SupplierLinkTypeName ProjectID   ParentSID   TargetCPI   SupplierCPI DefaultCPI
6dd94974-9e1b-44ce-8a3e-e1680f921a2e    -1  NULL    13958   Tracking NO_Kund_Cint4005   12963   42  EBAY    31962330    08a945eb-d780-4baa-892a-d4132e59afb5    80.213.119.232  1   2012-06-07 00:01:51.420 2012-06-07 00:02:05.327 3   1   Targeted / Reuse Supplier-Account Only  4637    c847ad2f-9a9f-4a81-8da3-a74d49f8143e    3   10  10
c2d53463-f81b-4156-87a7-e70203a4fc0e    -1  NULL    12200   Tracking NO_Kund_Cint4002   11205   42  EBAY    2513971 0e9d0e01-9009-40a8-a42e-65e1e6d4b1f8    85.167.23.63    1   2012-06-07 00:03:38.220 2012-06-07 00:03:55.143 3   38  Targeted / Reuse Supplier-Account Only  3857    4f74bbaf-0bb3-4430-9529-72c5dff36d3a    3   10  10
```

EDIT: how do you use an index to speed up queries?

UPDATE: MORE:

```
SessionID   int no  4   10  0   no  (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
SessionSID  nvarchar    no  128                 yes (n/a)   (n/a)   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
AccountID   int no  4   10  0   yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
RespondentID    int no  4   10  0   yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
SurveyID    int no  4   10  0   yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
SurveyNumber    int no  4   10  0   yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
ABCSurveyName   nvarchar    no  256                 yes (n/a)   (n/a)   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
SupplierID  int no  4   10  0   yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
SupplierName    nvarchar    no  128                 yes (n/a)   (n/a)   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
TargetID    int no  4   10  0   yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
TargetCPI   float   no  8   53  NULL    yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
ClientCPI   float   no  8   53  NULL    yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
QuotaCPI    float   no  8   53  NULL    yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
SupplierCPI float   no  8   53  NULL    yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
DefaultCPI  float   no  8   53  NULL    yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
EntryDate   datetime    no  8                   yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
LastDate    datetime    no  8                   yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
LK_RespondentPathID int no  4   10  0   yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
LK_ResponseStatusID int no  4   10  0   yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
IsLive  bit no  1                   yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
PID nvarchar    no  256                 yes (n/a)   (n/a)   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
IPAddress   nvarchar    no  32                  yes (n/a)   (n/a)   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
ClientLK_ResponseStatusID   int no  4   10  0   yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
ParentSID   nvarchar    no  128                 yes (n/a)   (n/a)   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
SurveyQualificationID   int no  4   10  0   yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
TargetName  nvarchar    no  128                 yes (n/a)   (n/a)   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
SupplierLinkID  int no  4   10  0   yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
LK_SupplierLinkTypeID   int no  4   10  0   yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
LK_SupplierLinkTypeName nvarchar    no  128                 yes (n/a)   (n/a)   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
EntryType   int no  4   10  0   yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
ExitType    int no  4   10  0   yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
ProjectID   int no  4   10  0   yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
ProjectName nvarchar    no  128                 yes (n/a)   (n/a)   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
CreateUserID    int no  4   10  0   yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
CreateDate  datetime    no  8                   yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
UpdateUserID    int no  4   10  0   yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
UpdateDate  datetime    no  8                   yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
LK_RecordStatusID   bit no  1                   yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
LK_CountryLanguageID    int no  4   10  0   yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
LK_CountryLanguageName  nvarchar    no  128                 yes (n/a)   (n/a)   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
SurveyAccountName   nvarchar    no  128                 yes (n/a)   (n/a)   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
SurveyAccountID int no  4   10  0   yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
```

EDIT: I needed some help from my boss, and now it's all figured out. there was another useful table to extract the IDs from, so using an index helped lots.

In MSSQL Server management studio I just ran a query like so to get that ID #:

```
select * from Surveys (nolock) where ABCSurveyName = '718184 Multicultural Shop '
```

Comment: can you post some sample data?  are you getting an error? what are you expecting to return from this query?

Comment: Are you sure you have at least one record in BI_sessions that has an EntryDate between '06-07-2011 00:00:01'  AND '06-07-2011 10:00:01'  (note the year "2011"), with an ABCSurveyName  like  'EBAY4263-718184%', and with a SupplierID of 42?  Print out one of the records you *expect* to see and verify this.  It shouldn't take more than 2 minutes cuttting/pasting different variations of this query in the SSMS GUI to figure out what's wrong :)

Comment: Why are you using `nolock`? Why are you using non-standard datetime formats? Have you tried `'yyyymmdd hh:mm:ss'` instead?

Comment: `BI_Sessions (nolock)` can obtain uncommitted data. So might be the data is rollback ?

Comment: @bluefeet - ok I'm on it, thanks

Comment: @AaronBertrand - well my boss does that :) and told me to use nolock, so i'm like yessir ok

Comment: Did you try like this `WHERE EntryDate BETWEEN   Convert(DateTime, '06-07-2011 00:00:01')  AND Convert(DateTime, '06-07-2011 10:00:01')  
`

Comment: @Kanavi - I can't image records from June of *last year* (2011) are "in rollback".  And I *hope* "EntryDate" is defined as a "DateTime" field, so there's no need for conversion.  I still believe doing a sample query, and finding a "known good record" in the MSSQL GUI, is the fastest/easiest way to debug this.  Who knows - maybe it's just a date error :)?

Comment: @Adel, You can find some info on indexes [here](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-server-index-basics/) but you don't need to speed things up until you [get them working](http://agileinaflash.blogspot.com/2009/03/make-it-work-make-it-right-make-it-fast.html).

Comment: See my answer below.  There are other things I'm noticed with the data other than what I already put.  Please post the table structure including datatypes (for all fileds - not just entry date).

Comment: @TimLehner - good point thanks!\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your entry date formats (in your sample data). One is 31:52.4 42:26.6.  Or 31:52.4 and LastDate is 42:26.6 (eyeballing). There seems to be a problem with the dates. **APPEARS DATA FOR ENTRY DATE IS '31:52.4'**

Where did this data come from?

Did you run the query without the where clause or was this provided to you?

Most importantly, What is its datatype in the table?

***EDIT - ADDING ON ***
Thanks for fixing the data - you have the wrong year in the date ranges if you are expecting to return your sample data with the query.

```
WHERE EntryDate BETWEEN   '06-07-2012 00:00:01'  AND '06-07-2012 10:00:01'
```

Also, your dates are in different formats between your query and data, which it will still return and is not an actual problem, but might make it easier to spot your mistake.

This query won't return the sample data based off of the surveyname condition either.  The column ABCSurvey name was in the data before, which I no longer see.  I now see FEDSUrveyname, so I'm not sure which one to talk about - BUT  before your edit '718184' was listed as data in a field named ABCSurveyName as was 'EBAY' listed in a separate field.  Nowhere did the data have those 2 together in one field, but your query condition says -
     ABCSurveyName  like  'EBAY4263-718184%'

I am not sure what the actual table structure is. I am guessing the condition should be broken out. 
     ABCSurveyName LIKE '%718184%'
SuplierId seems to 42, so I don't think you need the EBAY part included.

My guess is you need to change your `WHERE` CLause to

```
WHERE EntryDate BETWEEN   '06-07-2012 00:00:01'  AND '06-07-2012 10:00:01' --but i reccomend 'YYYY-MM-DD ...'  format for consistency
AND ABCSurveyName  like  '%718184%' --this is may even be ABCSurveyName = 718184 
AND SupplierID =  42
```

Again, I could be wrong in my assumption about 42 being EBAY, as I don't see the structures, so you may need to add in SupplierName = 'EBAY'.

So, to help you get any further if this doesn't work, I need to see the table structures because I'm making a lot of inferences here.  Is the sample data from the database, or are you copying it from a file?  Post the actual data from the database table if it is from a file. And let me know if it works. :)

***EDIT ADD ON FROM NEW INFO FROM OP**

It looks like there may be another table you are missing.  The sample data has 'ResponseID' which is not included in the schema.  I think you need a join.

Answer these questions please:  What is the sample data?  Where did it come from?  Is this data you are expecting to return from the query?
Thanks

AND TRY JUST THIS:(Remove the survey name part fro the clause, review the results and see if needs to be narrowed more)

```
WHERE EntryDate BETWEEN   '06-07-2012'  AND '06-08-2012'  
    --AND ABCSurveyName  like  'EBAY4263-718184%' 
    AND SupplierID =  42
```

Comment: Actually, I think that's two date fields, one (entrydate)being "31:52.4" and the other (lastdate) being "42:26.6".  Which I guess makes it look like those fields are time data, rather than datetime.  But you'd have to guess that his data is really hosed if that's the case.

Comment: Yes there is an issue with my data. let me look at this and fix it ASAP thanks

Comment: I think it may go beyond your dates as well.

Comment: @user1166147 - I just put in the updated, correct data. There are other problems? I know i should use indexes..

Comment: Thanks so much user1166147, and You are correct, 42 stands for EBAY .

Comment: Answer these questions please: What is the sample data? Where did it come from? Is this data you are expecting to return from the query? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you get results without the where clause the problem is exactly there. I don't now where exactly with no data to view. But in similar cases the best practice is to comment one by one your filters and check the results. Anyway my feeling is that the problem is in the date range. Try with:

```
WHERE EntryDate BETWEEN   '2011-06-07 00:00:01'  AND '2011-06-07 10:00:01'
```

or

```
WHERE EntryDate BETWEEN   '2011-07-06 00:00:01'  AND '2011-07-06 10:00:01'
```

because you know what 06 and 07 represent (dd-MM-yyyy or MM-dd-yyyy).

(Unlikely) also if this is about 13 days ago change the year to 2012 (??? it make sense to check by hour for something -quite- recent).

Comment: Thanks alot , and also for pointing me to look up default MSSQL date. it's dd-MM-yyyy

Comment: Well not yet but I'm confident the solution is near!

Comment: "AND ABCSurveyName  like 'EBAY4263-718184%'". All I see in sample data is "Tracking" for ABCSurveyName. This has no replation with EBAY...

Comment: Adel, have a small break, empty your head and see it again a bit later. You have it!

Comment: Just FYI `'2011-06-07'` can be just as ambiguous as `'dd-mm-yyyy'` - have you tried that with `SET LANGUAGE FRENCH`? Safest in this case would be `'yyyymmdd hh:mm:ss'`...

Comment: No, I have never worked with FR. Thanks for letting me know. I find it quite weird because I haven't met the pattern yyyy-dd-MM and I don't know who is using it or which country. I'll really appreciate some more info about this.

Comment: I know that SQL Server treats it as ydm instead of ymd when the language setting is French. I assume that represents how France might interpret it (or how they might have interpreted it when SQL Server was first created), as I don't know what other country would overrule France for that language.

Comment: Aaron, thanks a million for sharing this "little secret" with us.

Comment: I deal with this and many other common issues here : https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mishandling-date-range-queries.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Thanx for posting your data - you have the wrong year:

QUERY:

```
WHERE EntryDate BETWEEN   '06-07-2011 00:00:01'  AND '06-07-2011 10:00:01'
```

SAMPLE DATA:

```
2012-06-07 00:01:51.420 2012-06-07 00:02:05.327 3 
2012-06-07 00:03:38.220 2012-06-07 00:03:55.143 3
```

Whoops ;)

I'm guessing that's probably the whole problem.  Please let us know if changing the year on the query works!

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks so much for your response. I edited by query to match exactly the result that I posted below it. So as of now the date is just listed as month-day-year

Comment: @Adel - Cool.  And what about "ABCSurveyName"?  None of the rows in your sample data are "like 'EBAY4263-718184%'".